# Adding is not Working in Generic Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have a generic Dictionary

```
class GenericDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>();

    public void AddToGenericDictionary(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

I have declared a Class

```
class GenericInput1
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

In the main function, I have initialized the GenericInput1 class and Added into the GenericDIctionary

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         GenericInput1 inp1 = new GenericInput1 { Name = "An" };
         GenericInput1 inp2 = new GenericInput1 { Name = "B" };
         GenericInput1 inp3 = new GenericInput1 { Name = "C" };

         GenericDictionary<int, GenericInput1> genericIntKey = new GenericDictionary<int, GenericInput1>();

         genericIntKey.AddToGenericDictionary(1, inp1);
         genericIntKey.AddToGenericDictionary(2, inp2);
         genericIntKey.AddToGenericDictionary(3, inp3);

         GenericInput1 result2 = genericIntKey[3];
         Console.WriteLine(result2.Name);
    }
}
```

When I run the Program, it gives me the following exception :

> Unhandled Exception: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:
>   The given key was not present in the dictionary.

But If I try to add to generic dictionary using the built-in Add method, the program runs well.

Comment: Why do you create a class `GenericDictionary` when the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is already generic?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Actually I am at a very basic level of Generic Classes. So, I thought of having a Generic Dictionary also. Following your comment, I would like to ask you another question to clear my concept on this issue. We know List<T> itself is also generic and we can use it inside a generic class to add any type of objects. What is the main purpose of generic classes?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered in a comment. Have you read [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx)? However, since you know why   generic lists or dictionaries are useful(because you can use them with any types but still type-safe at compile-time), the same benefits has a custom generic class.

Comment: I suggest that you google inheritance vs. delegation, since you have them confused.

Comment: "We know List<T> itself is also generic and we can use it inside a generic class to add any type of objects. " -- No, you can only add objects of type T, whatever T is ... and you must specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code to

```
class GenericDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{

    public void AddToGenericDictionary(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        this.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

When overriding the dictionary, you do not need to implement the backing store.

But if you wish to implement your own Dictionary, have a look at [IDictionary Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx)

> Represents a generic collection of key/value pairs.

Comment: It's worth noting that a) `this.` isn't needed and b) the OP has inheritance and delegation confused.

Answer (score 2):

You are inheriting from `Dictionary`, so you don't need a backing field `Dictionary` in your class. So remove it and use the parent dictionary:

```
class GenericDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>();

    public void AddToGenericDictionary(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

to

```
class GenericDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public void AddToGenericDictionary(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        this.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```